# selection of data from a data rows

Tags: excel

I got wind speed data in excel table like this:

```
              (wind speed)           (wind direction)
```

Year|month|day|00:00|06:00|12:00|18:00||00:00|06:00|12:00|18:00||**X**|

1966|01|01|**5|12|6|8**||**60|360|270|50|**|**X**|

goal is to get in each day wind directin at wich was the max wind speed, for example: in firs jan. 1966 the max wind speed was 12 m/s at 06:00 and directon at the same time was **360**. I need that 360 in next **(X)** column. If there is equal max wind speed in several observaton times then is no mater which of those directions put in at next column.

Is it poseble do it in MS excel? If someone can help me it would be so great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the wind speed columns are D-G and the directions H-K then put the following formula in your column where the 'X' is (for row 2; copy it down the other rows)

```
=LOOKUP(MAX(D2:G2);D2:G2;H2:K2)
```

Comment: looks like it might work for but the result is wrong :(

Comment: What does wrong mean? Wrong value or error? (Probably the semicolons in the formula have to be commas. Depends on regional settings. I adapted it from German version)

Comment: Wrong values..., but i suppose the problem is somewhere in data structure. I tried commas - dosnt help, but thank you very much any way. I think I will be able to figure it out tomorrow :)